# Why does it require authentication to load DB values?

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

In my `spring-boot` + `reactjs` app, I have used spring security for authentication and role management purposes.

App is working fine but it requires successful authentication to load values for dropdowns, these dropdowns are dynamic and they are loaded from DB table. Actually, I have not added any security restrictions for the query database.

Can anybody help me to identify the issue?

This is my [git url](https://github.com/ChkBuk/myexamples/tree/master/SyneBiz)

Please look at `'src/main/java/com/example/polls/controller/FamilyController.java'` for example

I tried putting the following code to SecurityConfig.java but it did not work

```
http.authorizeRequests() 
    .antMatchers("/brands").permitAll()      
    .antMatchers("/familys").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/models").permitAll();
```

In the console, it shows

```
ERROR 9640 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.e.p.s.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint      : Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource
ERROR 9640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.p.s.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint      : Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

modified code:

```
         http
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/**/*.png",
                "/**/*.gif",
                "/**/*.svg",
                "/**/*.jpg",
                "/**/*.html",
                "/**/*.css",
                "/**/*.js"
                ) .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/brands").permitAll()      
            .antMatchers("/api/familys").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/models").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

   http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is mapped by `"/api/familys"`

```
....
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/familys")
public class FamilyController { 
....
```

So Your security pattern matchers should start first with `/api/`

And also make sure the order of declaring this end point before `.anyRequest().authenticated();` the order is imprtant in spring sec

```
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/api/brands/**").permitAll()      
  .antMatchers("/api/familys/**").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/api/models/**").permitAll()
.anyRequest()
        .authenticated();;
```